# Rails deliver_later getting Unsupported Argument Type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, actionmailer

I have changed mail delivery in my Rails application to implement `deliver_later` instead of `deliver_now`, and am running into an error message from ActiveJob.

The old mechanism was:

```
mail_collection.each &:deliver_now
```

The new mechanism is:

```
mail_collection.each do |m|
  m.deliver_later(wait_until: specified_time)
end
```

Now, when running my tests the line with the `deliver_later` method is throwing the error:

> Minitest::UnexpectedError:         ActiveJob::SerializationError:
> Unsupported argument type: Address

If I change `deliver_later` to `deliver_now` and remove the options, the problem clears. I have inspected the objects and verified that they are Mail Messages and also verified via a call to `m.method(:deliver_later)`, that it is using:

> <Method: ActionMailer::MessageDelivery#deliver_later(options=...)
> /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionmailer-6.1.7/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:98>

I have replaced with `specified_time` with `Time.now` to ensure that this wasn't the root cause, and I am getting the same error.

I have updated Sidekiq to 7.0, as I saw some discussion of a similar issue with earlier versions of Sidekiq, but no love.

Any suggestions on where to look for a solution would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `deliver_later` method it will serialize arguments that you're passing to the `m` and later on these arguments will be deserialized.

It looks like you are passing a custom `Address` object as an argument and ActiveJob doesn’t really know how to serialize/deserialize this object.

There are two possible solutions:

1. You don't pass a custom `Address` object but i.e. only attributes with supported types.
   Here you can find a list of supported argument types https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/SerializationError.html
2. You write a custom serializer for the `Address`, here is a blog post that explains it in more detail https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/09/11/rails-6-custom-serializers-for-activejob-arguments.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Originally, I thought this couldn't be correct because the to/from were simply being assigned strings. However, upon looking more closely I see that these strings were being changed to Address objects. This raises the question: if deliver_later was introduced in Rails 4.x and custom serializers were introduced in Rails 6, how could deliver later have ever worked prior to Rails 6??

Comment: I believe that in Rails 4.x you would have to serialize an Address object on your own and then pass the serialized object as argument. Otherwise the `ActiveJob::SerializationError` would be thrown.

Comment: For those with a generous heart, I have a follow up question on implementing the serializer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74853063/trying-to-implement-rails-activejob-serializer

Answer (score 0):

### ************* Final Update *************

For what it is worth, I was never able to get the serializer to work, which is just as well because that was not the root problem.

The code I was executing looks something like:

```
create_emails.each do |m|
  m.deliver_later(wait_until: next_time_slot)
end
```

The real issue was that in the method `create_emails`, there were methods being called that had parameters that were not among the list of serializable objects for ActiveJob. What led me astray was that the email I was sending had an Address parameter, however one of the methods under `create_emails` did as well.

So, I thought the problem was with the sending of the emails, when it was actually with the creation of the emails, which tells me that the block sending the email is passed and executed instead of the email itself, is *really* not at all intuitive.  Guess I'll need to dig into the source code to fully understand what is going on.

Once I changed all of the methods under `create_emails` to have parameters that could be handled by ActiveJob, the problem was resolved.