# Trying to implement Rails ActiveJob Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, rails-activejob

I am trying to implement an ActiveJob Serializer in Rails 6.1.7 so that I can deliver email with the deliver_later method. Examples I see of this say that I should extend the class

```
ActiveJob::Serializers::ObjectSerializer
```

and configure the serializer in my application config

```
Rails.application.config.active_job.custom_serializers << MySerializer.
```

My application is a bit different, in that the configuration lives in namespace (cannot change this) and this is causing some problems. I have tried the following:

```
class MySerializer < ActiveJob::Serializer::ObjectSerializer
---
end
```

as well as

```
module MyNamespace
  class MySerializer < ActiveJob::Serializer::ObjectSerializer
  ---
  end
end
```

I have put the serializer under `app/serializers`.

I have tried to set the Active Job setting both with:

```
module MyNamespace
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.active_job.custom_serializers << MySerializer
  end 
end
```

which is where all other application config setting are made, which ends up with the error:

```
uninitialized constant MyNamespace::Application::MySerializer (NameError)
```

If I pull it completely outside of the namespace with

```
Rails.application.config.active_job.custom_serializers << MySerializer
```

I get the error message:

```
uninitialized constant MySerializer (NameError)
```

Any ideas regarding what I am doing wrong that is causing my serializer to not be found?

Answer (score -1):

Namespacing in serializers, active job or not, works just fine, but you have to identify the namespace in each place that its called.

**Config:**

```
Rails.application.config.active_job.custom_serializers << MyNamespace::MySerializer
```

**Location:**

```
app/serializers/my_namespace/my_serializer.rb
```

**Job:**

```
def perform(*args)
  # do some stuff with your serialized item by calling- note the method serialize here is just a default and you could have whatever you need here

  MyNamespace::MySerializer.serialize(args[0]).serializeable_hash
end
```

**Inheritance:**

```
module MyNamespace
  class MySerializer < ActiveJob::Serializers::ObjectSerializer
    def serialize(object)
      #....
    end
  end
end

# note that in your example, Serializer was singular instead of plural
```

Comment: Thank you for catching my typo and for your suggested configuration. Unfortunately, even when I place the file in the suggested path, include the serializer class in the module and supply the namespace on the configuration, I am still getting the same error.